# Shopify - liquid : Collection returning empty all_products array on paginated page

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to load `collection.all_products` expression to load all the products of a collection on collections page, but I am experiencing an issue with pagination.

I want to load all the products a collection is containing. So, I am using pagination to set limit on how many product it should load, otherwise it only loads 50 products.

I am using following expression to set pagination product limit:

`{% paginate collection.all_products by collection.all_products_count %}`

with expectation that collection.all_products should contain all the products.

The expressions works as expected, i.e. returns array of all the products when it is on the first page of the collection, but when I switch to different paginated page of the collection, it returns empty array for all_products.

One thing I noticed is, on paginated page, collection.all_products_count still returns correct number but collection.all_products is empty.

Please, If anyone have faced a similar issue and know a workaround to load all products of a collection on different page, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using Debut theme.

Comment: Out of curiousity, how many products are in the collection, and what's the pagination_by set to?

Comment: Hello Dave, collection has at max about 250 products. The theme setting is set to paginate at 16 products.

Answer (score 3):

Is `all_products` a method of the collection object in the first place? According to [Shopify's documentation on collection](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/collection), the method to call would be `collection.products`.

https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/theme-tags#paginate

May explain why `collection.all_products` is empty.

Comment: Hello @mdlanglais, The collection.all_products returns empty result if I paginate, otherwise it contains 50 products of the collection. I found a workaround for the problem I was facing though.

Comment: No, @mdlangais is right - you're paginating `collection.all_products` when you should be paginating `collection.products` - good catch!  The correct syntax is `{% paginate collection.products by ### %}` (where `###` would be replaced by a number or a liquid variable representing a number)

Comment: Thank you @Dave B